# Error en C# Windows forms - TextBox vacío o Null

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un problema en mi programa y es muy básico, consiste en introducir dos valores y multiplicarlos en una ventana.

El problema es que al dejar una caja de texto vacía, no ocurre lo esperado (*escribir **`"error"`** en el resultado*), simplemente salta un error.

Este es el código:

```
            double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor1.Text);
            double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor1.Text);

            if (txtValor1.Text == "")
            {
                resultado.Text = "error";
            }

            if (txtValor2.Text == "")
            {
                resultado.Text = "error";
            }

            if (txtValor1.Text == "" && txtValor2.Text == "")
            {
                resultado.Text = "error";
            }

            double multiplicar = num1 * num2;
            string Multiplicar = Convert.ToString(multiplicar);

            resultado.Text = (Multiplicar);
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Tu codigo esta desordenado y por eso el error. Primero deberias verificar si los campos de texto estan vacios (cosa que haces dos veces) y luego, si no estan vacios, hacer el convert. Verifica la logica de tu codigo, linea por linea y te vas a dar cuenta

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta e indica el error o excepción que te da.

Comment: Solo debes de eliminar los dos primeros `if`. En el 3er `if` reemplaza `&&` por `||` y a ese mismo `if` agregale un `else` el cual contendra el fragmaneto de codigo de coversion y multiplicacion. Las variable `num1` y `num2` las puedes inicializar en cero.

Comment: muchísimas gracias!!! Problema resuelto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En principio y según tu código, estás asignando a las variables `num1` y `num2` el mismo valor, el del `txtValor1`.

```
double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor1.Text);
double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor1.Text);
```

Ahí es donde puede estar tu principal error. Asigna a cada variable su correspondiente valor:

```
double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor1.Text);
double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor2.Text);
```

Por otra parte, tu código **no está lo suficientemente optimizado**. Prueba de esta manera:

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtValor1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtValor2.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor1.Text);
                double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor2.Text);
                resultado.Text = Convert.ToString.(num1 * num2);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                resultado.Text = "error: " + ex.Message;
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            resultado.Text = "error";
        }
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, pero si el OP tiene problema con algo como esto, entonces imaginate al OP viendo la negacion y el try/catch. Creo que deberias haberle puesto dos ejemplo: uno sencillo que este al nivel del OP y luego el ejemplo que ya colocaste. igual hay van mis +1.

Comment: +1 Por no solo enfocarse en solucionar el problema, sino también en sugerir una optimización del código.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes a la hora de convertir a Double.

```
   double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor1.Text); //Error aquí al tratar de convertir cadena vacía a double
```

Para evitar este problema debes hacer la validación antes de hacer el Convert de la siguiente manera:

```
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;

        if (txtValor1.Text == "")
        {
            resultado.Text = "error";
        }
        else
        {
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor1.Text);
        }

        if (txtValor2.Text == "")
        {
            resultado.Text = "error";
        }
        else
        {
          num2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor2.Text);
        }



        if (txtValor1.Text == "" && txtValor2.Text == "")
        {
            resultado.Text = "error";
        }

        double multiplicar = num1 * num2;
        string Multiplicar = Convert.ToString(multiplicar);

        resultado.Text = Multiplicar;
```

Pero si quieres una mejor validación utiliza Double.TryParse.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Este codigo sigue estando mal. Siempre va a mostrar 0 en el campo resultado.text, sin importar si hay errores o no

Answer (score 0):

puedes poner un return en la función ha y num1 y num2 reciben el mismo TextBox

```
double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor1.Text);
        double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor2.Text);

        if (txtValor1.Text == "")
        {
            resultado.Text = "error";
            return;
        }

        if (txtValor2.Text == "")
        {
            resultado.Text = "error";
            return;
        }

        if (txtValor1.Text == "" && txtValor2.Text == "")
        {
            resultado.Text = "error";
            return;
        }

        double multiplicar = num1 * num2;
        string Multiplicar = Convert.ToString(multiplicar);

        resultado.Text = (Multiplicar);
```